# Selenium Cannot Locate element by id

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The below is a selenium python code where I am trying to click Sign In by sending the login details via selenium. However, when I am using `find_element_by_id` method to locate the username and password input area the scripts throws an error
`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="usernameOrEmail"]"}`. But, when I am inspect the webpage on the input text type it shows me the same id which I have mentioned in my script.

P.S: When the selenium opens up the browser please maximize the windows else the code will not work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C://Arighna/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.fool.com/")
print(driver.title)
mybutton = driver.find_element_by_id('login-menu-item')
mybutton.click()
delay = 5
WebDriverWait(driver,delay)
email_area = driver.find_element_by_id('usernameOrEmail')
email.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
email_area.send_keys('ar')
WebDriverWait(driver,delay)

pwd_area = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
pwd_area.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
pwd_area.send_keys('1234')
WebDriverWait(driver,delay)


login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login')
login_btn.click()
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above code as this one and it worked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C://Arighna//chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.fool.com/")
mybutton = driver.find_element_by_id('login-menu-item')
mybutton.click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"))
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']").send_keys("Selenium")


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']"))
)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']").send_keys("Selenium")

singin_bttn = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login')
singin_bttn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Email / Username** field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.fool.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#login-menu-item"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#usernameOrEmail"))).send_keys("SouradipRoy")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.fool.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='login-menu-item']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"))).send_keys("SouradipRoy")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: fool]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)